# proving the Klein 4 group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If ker $f = \{ (1), (12)(34), (14)(23), (13)(24) \}$, which is the Klein 4 group, how do I prove that it is an Abelian group? Do I just show that each element in the ker $f$ is commutative to prove this?

Comment: Elements are not commutative. Elements can commute, and if all elements commute, the operation is commutative. In this case yes, just check all the compositions.

Answer (score 14):

Let $G$ be a non-abelian group. Then $ab\ne ba$ for some $a,b\in G$. Then clearly $a\ne 1$ and $b\ne 1$ and $a\ne b$.  Also $ab\notin\{1,a,b\}$ and $ba\notin\{1,a,b\}$. That already makes five distinct elements $1,a,b,ab,ba$.

Comment: (One can then conclude that all groups of order four are abelian.)

Comment: @user1729 In fact, all groups of order $\le 4$. And since $5$ is a prime, ...

Comment: Well, yeah, but you haven't proven that...

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to prove it for this particular group, because ALL 4-element groups are abelian, you can prove that like this:

Suppose that for all $a\in G$, we have that $a^2=1$, or equivalently $a=a^{-1}$, then the group is abelian:

$$(ab)=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$$

If our supposition is not true, then there exists an element $a$ such that $a^2\neq 1$ different from $1$, and the group generated by this element, by Lagrange's theorem, must have order $4$, so $\langle a\rangle=G$, so the group is cyclic and abelian.

Comment: You can, of course shorten this by observing that the OP's group satisfies the property that $a^2=1$ for all $a\in G$.

Answer (score 7):

There are only $4$ elements, so just check by hand that $ab = ba$ for any $a, b$.  It's true automatically if either $a$ or $b$ is $1$ so actually there are only three pairs to check.

Comment: So, for example would I check that $(12)(34) = (34)(12)$?

Comment: No, that's true and shows you that $(1 \ 2)$ and $(3 \ 4)$ commute, but these aren't elements in your group.  You have to show, for example, that $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)(1 \ 4)(2 \ 3) = (1 \ 4)(2 \ 3)(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$ so that you can conclude that $(1 \ 2)(3 \ 4)$ and $(1 \ 4)(2 \ 3)$ commute.

Comment: oh okay. I see what you mean.

Comment: And, if you check that the product of two distinct nonidentity elements is the third, then there are only two pairs to check.

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly less direct approach--one you probably would not think of if you were attempting a problem like this for the first time)--but hopefully you (or others) will find this alternative solution to be instructive.

***Theorem***: Let $G$ be a group such that every element of $G$ other than the identity has order $2$. Then $G$ is abelian.

***Proof:*** Let $x$ and $y$ be any two elements of $G$. Then we must show that $xy=yx$. I will write $e$ to indicate the identity element.
$$e=(xy)^2=xyxy$$
$$x^{-1}=x^{-1}e=x^{-1}xyxy=yxy$$
$$y^{-1}x^{-1}=y^{-1}yxy=xy$$
Now note that since $x$ and $y$ each have order $2$, $x=x^{-1}$ and $y=y^{-1}$, so $yx=xy$.

I leave it up to you to verify that the non-identity elements of the group in question have order $2$.

Comment: and $(xy)^2 = e$ because all elements are either identity or of order 2